# Tomcat авторизация. Возврат на защищенную страницу

Tags: apache, jsp, tomcat

Проблема состоит в том, что после разлогирования пользователя- он может стрелкой "назад" вернуться на защищенные страницы. Редактировать он их при этом не может, его скидывает на страницу авторизации. Думал, что проблема в кешировании - попробовал его выключить, не помогло. Так же добавлял костыли в духе редиректов, в случае, если пользователь не залогирован, как на jsp страницах, так и в левых сервлетах. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class NoCacheFilter implements Filter {
    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
        response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.

        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }
```